# I can't open any UDP port(inbound)

Tags: debian, iptables

I am setting up a little IPTable.

This is my current config:

```
# Accept everything on the loopback interface
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
# Accept ICMP
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
# Drop oddball packets
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -f -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP
# Accept packets that are part of established connections
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
# Accept selected incoming connections
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
#TeamSpeak
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 9987 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 10011 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 30033 -j ACCEPT

# Reject incoming connections that aren't explicitly accepted
iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT
```

I tested every port if it is open or not.
The only port that is NOT open is port 9987, which is using UDP.

I tried to set any port as open with UDP and it didn't work.

When I open port 9987 as TCP it works.

I am using Debian 7 and have no idea.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: Like the title says. I can't open the port. But after a whole system reboot, it worked. I think I had to restart TeamSpeak.

Comment: That has nothing to do with your firewall, then.

Comment: But I thought the problem was in the iptable.

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting the whole system or restart TeamSpeak solved the problem.